# get user last input command-line input

Tags: python, input, msvcrt

is it possible to get the user's last input?

I am working in a program that needs to check every char, that the user enters.

my question how do I check if the user pressed the Up button, then get the last user input and display it

**like when you press the up button in a cmd, it gives you the last input you entered**

here's my simple test program

```py
import msvcrt
def test_input(prompt="",end="\n"): # Test input 
    string = ""
    point_zore = 0
    while True:
            key = msvcrt.getch()
            print(key)
            if key == b"\r":
                break
            elif key == b'\xe0':
                char = msvcrt.getch()
                if str(char) == "H": # when the user press the up button
                    # do stuff
                    pass
                'H' # Up button
                b'\xe0'
                'P' # Down button
                b'\xe0'
                'K' # Right button? 
                b'\xe0'
                'M' # Left button?
                print(char)
            elif key == b'\x08':
                string = string[:-1]

            else:
                try:
                    string+=key.decode()
                except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                    print(e)
    return string
```

I tried to search in google but I found nothing **so I am asking the StackOverflow community**

> if that is impossible I understand

Answer (score 0):

try saving everything the user has entered and than if the user pressed the up key print the last thing the user has entered